# sizeof in struct

Tags: c, struct, int, sizeof

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <malloc.h>

struct Student {
       char name[100];
       int id;
       char major[50];
       char address[200];
};

int main()
{

     struct Student st;

     strcpy(st.name, "Chuck");
     st.id = 20001;
     strcpy(st.major, "Computer Science");
     strcpy(st.address, "1st Street");

     printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", sizeof(st), sizeof(st.name),sizeof(st.id), sizeof(st.major), sizeof(st.address));

     return 0;
}
```

The output is 356 100 4 50 200.
Why is sizeof(st) 356, not 354?
And I tried this without having int and the output was 350 100 50 200, so I assume the problem is in the integer.

Comment: You did not tell which compiler, processor, operating system... are you using

Comment: Don't use `%d` to print `size_t`s. Use `%zu` instead.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It doesn't matter.  The answer is the same for all platforms.

Comment: my bad.. I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: @DietrichEpp: It surely does matter in theory. I'm sure that an hypothetical 128 bits word machine with 64 bits `int` will align fields differently than my GCC on Linux x86 in 32 bits mode! There is no guarantee that an `int` is 32 bits (if you want that, `#include <stdint.h>` and use `int32_t`). And some 16 bits machines had 16 bits `int`, e.g. original PCs with Intel 8086 in the 1980s.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The question is "why does this happen", not "how are fields aligned on my computer".  The answer to "why" is the same on all platforms, and you don't need to know how wide `int` is to answer the question.

Comment: BTW `malloc` is today in `<stdlib.h>` and the `<malloc.h>` header is deprecated (or useful for other non-standard functions that you don't use).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to padding between `struct` members. The padding is necessary to ensure that each data member is correctly [aligned in memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). The exact alignment requirements depend on your architecture.

Due to this, you cannot assume that the size of a `struct` equals the sum of the sizes of its members.

Comment: "In your particular case, the int is getting aligned at a four-byte boundary, requiring two bytes of padding before it" -- Nope; 100 % 4 == 0. The correct answer is that the struct is aligned to a multiple of 4 bytes (354 % 4 == 2).

Comment: @JimBalter: You are quite right, thanks.

Comment: As a side note, this also means that the order of members declarations inside a struct may affect its size.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Like `sizeof(struct {int a; char b; char c;})` == 8 but `sizeof(struct {char a; int b; char c;})` == 12 on the OP's platform.

Comment: precisely. It's basically like playing with Lego.

Comment: NPE: I like how you added the "thanks" in an edit ... I appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

Each non-first field in a structure may be preceded by a gap (or padding). The compiler is adding gaps to fit the need of your processor and of the ABI conventions.

You should trust the compiler, it is laying out `struct` as required by the implementation.

Some compilers provide extensions to alter or improve the structure's layout, e.g. the [type attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) of GCC for `aligned` or `packed`.

Don't feel the paddings and gaps inside a `struct` as an issue, but as asset: the compiler tries very hard to satisfy the processor, the ABI conventions, etc...

Most compilers don't reorder fields in structures (GCC used to have a rarely useful optimization which did that, but that optimization has been removed, because sometimes it hurted - e.g. with LTO).

If you care about `struct` size and if you don't care about the order of the fields, you may reorder them cleverly. But the most dense order could be architecture dependent.

BTW, the C standard does not even guarantee that an `int` is 32 bits or of a larger size and alignment than `char` (even if that is very common). It provides `<stdint.h>` and `int32_t` for that purpose. I suspect you would not observe any padding or gap if compiling for a 16 bits machine on which `int`-s are 16 bits (e.g. the original PC AT with Intel 8086 processor from the 1980s, or some cheap 16 bits microcontroller).

Comment: "Each non-first field in a structure may be preceded by a gap (or padding). " -- In this case, none of the fields is preceded by a gap; the gap comes after the last field, to pad the struct size to a multiple of 4.